# calling a row form MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I dont know much about MYSQL. But i need to fetch the number of review articles that a user uploaded.
To call this data, I have my database named "abc", inside I have a table named `zxc_review_stats` .... inside this table there are several columns, but the one I need to fetch is named "reviews"

[image]

So how can I fetch the number from the column reviews? this is what ive got so far:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from `zxc_review_stats` WHERE `owner` = <<userid>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work.

```
<?php 

// ... your code    

// Assuming $user_id is defined and holds the user's id.
$query = "SELECT reviews"
       . " FROM zxc_review_stats"
       . " WHERE user_id='" . $user_id . "'";

// do something with this query
?>
```

Comment: I'd avoid mixing PHP and SQL in the answer unless you can make it valid syntax (by expanding the answer).

Comment: @MarcusAdams I've edited my answer and sprinkled some php over it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to pull is the value of the reviews field for that user:

```
Select `reviews` FROM `zxc_review_stats` WHERE `user_id`=user //replace user with the actual number
```

Comment: i want that each user to know how many reviews he uploaded on the site when is logged in. 
If i change this last part: `owner` = '$user_id';
will it take the logged user info and search his reviews?

Comment: My answer is essentially the same as Mehmet's above, though his has more clarity.  My answer won't do anything that his would not.